# (VB.NET) Scroll with mouse wheel

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar

This question might seems stupid, but it really annoys me. :p

I use TabPages, where I activated AutoScroll, so when the content doesn't fit a TabPage, a scrollbar appears.

But I would like to scroll when I use my mouse wheel, which is far easiest than clicking on the scrollbar.

Does I have to write something in the form Loader?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks !

Comment: What have your search results gave you?  Could you post why those solutions haven't helped?  SO is much better for helping fix existing code.  (Others will put this as SO is not a code-writing service)

Comment: This is already implemented without you having to help.  Why it doesn't work for you is completely unguessable.

Comment: @JimmySmith Of course, i just tried the script from this site : 
http://www.thescarms.com/VBasic/ScrollForm.aspx

And replaced all the VScroll1 by VScroll because there was a "non declared variable error"

Didn't work, all the code was underlined, as i didn't understand the code i droppet it anyway..

I completely understand that you won't write the code, but tips would be really useful, i almost finished my soft and that's one of the last points left :p

The problem is that I don't know if i can modify a scrollbar with code if it's generated automatically.

Comment: @HansPassant I use a class to modify the skin of my form, do you think there is a link? I'll try a new project without it to see

EDIT: Same thing with lambda TabControl :( I'm lost

Comment: Why do you need that "script" from that site. Forms have this functionality by default. They will show a scroll bar if the content goes out of window. It's for VB6, but your tag (and code) says VB.NET

Comment: @Keith Yeah, the scrollbar appears, but what i want is to scroll with my mouse wheel, like in a net browser. I can do it in the form, but not on a TabePage...

EDIT: I think i'll use the easy way : A panel in each tabPages (it works well on panels)

If anyone have a better solution ^^

Comment: @CorentinPrune just trying to be polite.  I didn't downvote, but we'll need more to work with is the gist of it.  In .NET, the scrollbars (from my experience) just sorta work.  But is this .NET or VB6???  You mentioned an error, but where is the code where you're getting the error?

Comment: I already linked an url with the code that i tried to use. But my problem looks more like a bug than a code problem. As everyone said sooner, I normally could scroll using my mouse wheel. It works on panels, on forms, but not on TabPages. So, one of the solutions is to find how to fix these tabPages. Else I'll have to work with panel in each TabPages, and another problem will come...

Anyway I'll do some research for the solution alone, I have the feeling that I'll be downvoted everytime i'll post a comment on this topic.
Thanks for the help, and for being polite.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found what I was searching for, I post it in case somebody encounter the same problem as me.

So in fact, you need to make the tabs "active" to scroll. I personnally use this code hich is a bit tricky but works well :

```
Private Sub TAB_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TAB.MouseClick
    Me.ActiveControl = Me.TAB.SelectedTab
End Sub
```

Where TAB is my TabControl

Thanks for your help guys